# Multiple global functions in the same CUDA source file

Tags: cuda

Can I write two separate global functions, that compute different things, in the same CUDA source file? Something like this:

```
__global__ void Ker1(mpz_t *d,mpz_t *c,mpz_t e,mpz_t n )
{
    int i=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    mpz_powm (d[i], c[i], e, n);

}

__global__ void Ker2(mpz_t *d,mpz_t *c,mpz_t d, mpz_t n)
{
    int i=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    mpz_powm(c[i], d[i],d, n);

}


int main()
{
    /* ... */
    cudaMemcpy(decode_device,decode_buffer,memSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    Ker1<<<dimGrid , dimBlock >>>( d_device,c_device,e,n );
    Ker2<<<dimGrid , dimBlock>>>(c_device,d_device,d,n);
    cudaMemcpy(decode_buffer,decode_device,memSize,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

If not, how would you do something like this?

Comment: Just try it out...

Comment: I tried to answer your question about different kernels written in the same source file. But please, consider improving your question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite unclear what you're asking, but after 3 readings I assume : *"Can I write several Kernels in the same source file ?"*.
Your can write as much kernel launchs as you want in your main function.

An example here on page 9 :

```
...
cudaMemcpy( dev1, host1, size, H2D ) ;
kernel2 <<< grid, block, 0 >>> ( ..., dev2, ...  ) ;
kernel3 <<< grid, block, 0 >>> ( ..., dev3, ...  ) ;
cudaMemcpy( host4, dev4, size, D2H ) ;
...
```

From : [Streams and concurrency webinar](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf)

The calls will be asynchronous by default, so as soon as the kernel is launched in the GPU, the CPU will treat the instructions that follow.
To force synchronization you have to use **cudaDeviceSynchronize()**, or any memory transfer via cudaMemcpy that forces synchronization by itself.

Source : the [CUDA FAQ](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq).

> Q: Can the CPU and GPU run in parallel?
>   Kernel invocation in CUDA is asynchronous, so the driver will return control to the application as soon as it has launched the kernel.
>
> The "cudaThreadSynchronize()" API call should be used when measuring
>   performance to ensure that all device operations have completed before
>   stopping the timer.
>
> CUDA functions that perform memory copies and that control graphics
>   interoperability are synchronous, and implicitly wait for all kernels
>   to complete.

By the way, if you don't need to synchronize between kernels, they can be executed concurrently if your GPU has the required compute capability (CC) :

> Q: Is it possible to execute multiple kernels at the same time? 
>   Yes. GPUs of compute capability 2.x or higher support concurrent kernel execution and launches.

(still readen from the CUDA FAQ).

Comment: This is because your second kernel has two parameters called "d", even if one of them is a pointer. This can't work with any compiler.
My answer still stands for what you are asking in your question.
By the way it seems you are just pasting your errors and doing no effort to resolve them, expecting us to give you an error-free version o f your code. This a very exhausting conduct, I will stop there for this topic.

Comment: you're totally right, I don't remark it for d, and I will make effort for the future and may be I won't ask silly questions ... I take it in the good way so gracias.